# three.js - let user upload .gltf / .glb 3d model

Tags: javascript, file-upload, three.js, uploading, gltf

Hi just started learning **three.js**

Is there any way to let the **user upload** his .glb / .gltf 3d model and see it on the canvas right away?

I'm thinking maybe is possible with PHP since I'm using WordPress?

Can PHP and JS even communicate together that way?

Or it is better uploading only with JS?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Have a look at Don McCurdy GLTF viewer.

https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer

Comment: Technically Don's viewer doesn't "upload" the model, although another website could.  The drag-and-drop operation just causes JavaScript in the client's browser to read the data and add it to the scene.  It would take a bit of extra logic to upload it from the client to a server, and of course the server would need some kind of storage mechanism to receive it.

Comment: ok, thank you. https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/  that's all I need for now.

but it would be nice if we could discuss further actual uploading .glb on the server in some later time.

thank you

Comment: Now I'm searching for some other three.js events, it's well hard to find; like the animation (rotation, movement) of an object on mouse click event, I get these but without animation. 

This is maybe better to ask in the form of the new question and topic

Comment: should I "click to accept this answer", I'm not familiar with the stack rules

Comment: Accept only if my answer was helpful to you. You should also create new question if you want to ask something not related to this one.